# Can I create a win32 Project in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to debug and build win32 programs in VScode, can I do it?
I have a C++ win32 Project in Visual Studio 2012 and I much prefer Visual Studio Code for editing source files.
Is there a way to work with Visual Studio C++ C++ win32 projects in Visual Studio Code?
debug and build win32 programs in VScode

Comment: Something like it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-170

Comment: just edit in VSC and compile/debug in VS

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can use Visual Studio C++ toolset from command line for compiling.
Oficial notes about it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/building-on-the-command-line?view=msvc-170

But **you need to download Visual Studio**, for downloading compiler and other toolset.